# What does “schreib mal WA” mean?

Tags: translation, colloquial

It might be short for “Ich schreib dir mal bei/in wa” or something, but I still can’t figure it out.

It was in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/einxfuereinu/status/533906365786648576).

Here’s a summary of the main part of the exchange:

> Schatz, holst du Kaffee
>   Ach nö, geh du
>   Nö du!
>   Du liebst mich nicht!
>   Du auch!
>   Liebt uns das Kind? Schreib mal WA

Comment: Can you give us some context? While one interpretation suggests itself, there are alternatives and the only way to be certain is knowing the context.

Comment: sure - it was in this tweet, joking about something: https://twitter.com/einxfuereinu/status/533906365786648576

Comment: We can only take guesses, but you won't get a definite answer on this. The context is strange anyway ("Liebt uns das Kind?" -> Huh?). It doesn't make sense to write "WA" in upper-case.

Answer (score 11):

In this context *WA* means *WhatsApp* so the sentence

> Schreib [mir] mal [auf] WhatsApp.

would mean:

> Text me on WhatsApp.

Comment: Note that this would be very sloppy grammar, approximately equivalent to the English “Write WhatsApp”.

Answer (score 4):

I interpret `wa` (as well as `wat`) as short for `was`, which is itself short for `etwas`.

The difference is maybe caused by a typo or it is written as in spoken language.

So the sentence means `text something!` as a request to you.

A similar example is `Komm ma her!`, where `ma` is meant to say `mal` (which is itself short for `einmal`) but the `l` is in certain regions not pronounced in spoken language.

Comment: "...or it is written as in spoken language." -> "wa" in spoken language for "was"? You're sure on that?

Comment: Yeah, the German "was" (which is itself short for "etwas"), not the English "was".

Comment: Of course German... never ever heard it, though.

Comment: I edited my answer to contain that notice now. "Mal" or "einmal" is used for example in "Bist du schon (ein)mal Achterbahn gefahren?", which is in English "Have you ever taken a ride on a rollercoaster?"

Comment: I am native German, and I know about "mal" vor "einmal" which is pretty common. And I know that "etwas" is shortened to "was". But shortened to "wa"? It can only be a typo. – Why is it written in upper-case anyway?

Comment: I grew up with German as formal language (in CH), and I also haven't seen "wa" as an abbreviation yet, but rather in spoken (perhaps fast speaking) language. Agree with it being a typo in the question. No idea about it being upper-case either...

Comment: @Em1 *Wa* is an abbreviation of *was*, which again can be an abbreviation of *etwas*... I thought that *wa* is quite common, or at least widely understood. The upper-case could be for intonation.

Comment: @Grantwalzer No, neither common nor widely understood.

Comment: @Em1 I can remember it being used frequently on television. And pretty much everybody I know knows it. Even people from Austria (where it's *wos* in most dialects).

Comment: @Grantwalzer Where are from? Southern Germany, I guess?

Comment: @Em1 *Wa* makes you think of Southern Germany? Where are you from, Austria?

Comment: @Grantwalzer Because most times when something is unfamiliar to me, it's from Southern Germany dialects. And you brought up Austrian German, which is similar to Southern German in many aspects.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the context, and the origin of the quote (interpunction added)

> Schreib mal, wa!

we can assume that **wa** was used as an [interjection](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjektion). *Wa* is colloquially used  in some regions in the meaning of *[nicht wahr](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nicht_wahr)* to strengthen the preceding imperativ (*schreib mal*).

Now that we see the full context in the question's edit it appears to be an abbreviation or acronym rather than the interjection mentioned above.

I am not aware of any chat slang acronym *WA*, therefore it may also be the initials of the sender we have here.

Comment: Yes, "wa" is an interjection commonly used in some regions. But even without context totally unlikely.

Comment: @Em1: that's why I added the edit here. Written in lower case I couldn't think of anything but an interjection but now that we have the whole context and it is uppercase it's likely an acronym or the initials of the author.