# Schick uns eine Whatsapp

Tags: grammar

Mein Radiosender will mir neuerdings nahelegen, daß ich bei Musikwünschen eine Whatsapp schicken solle:

> Für Musikwünsche, schicke uns eine Whatsapp!

Das geht mir ehrlich gesagt ziemlich auf den Senkel, da ich zwar *die* Whatsapp installiert habe, diese aber nicht "schicken" kann. Ich könnte aber eine *Whatsapp Nachricht* oder eine *Nachricht per Whatsapp* schicken; warum wird mir dies nicht angeboten?

Dieses Phänomen scheint dem des "Blog posten" ähnlich zu sein, wo Leute neuerdings auch nur "einen neuen Blog reinstellen", statt "einen neuen Beitrag im Blog reinzustellen."

Gibt es für dieses Phänomen eine Bezeichnung? Ich weiß nicht einmal genau, wie ich's beschreiben sollte. Übergeordnete Systeme werden wie Teile des Systems behandelt‽ Ist das eine Form der Verallgemeinerung? Sollte dann nicht wenigstens die Grammatik anders sein? Man sagt ja auch nicht *"Schick mir eine Post"*, sondern höchstens *"schick mir Post"*. Warum also *"eine Whatsapp"*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ohne eine Bezeichnung für das Phänomen zu haben, handelt es sich um eine Konstruktion analog zu

> Schick' mir eine SMS.

Wie [WhatsApp](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whatsapp) bezeichnet auch [SMS](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sms)/[MMS](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_Messaging_Service) korrekterweise einen Dienst / eine Anwendung, nicht die Nachricht selbst, die allerdings umgangssprachlich ebenso bezeichnet wird<sup>1</sup>. WhatsApp ersetzt bzw. ergänzt die ältere SMS funktional wie begrifflich, und eben auch im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch.

Auch wenn es aus technischer Sicht falsch und aus sprachlicher Sicht zumindest unpräzise ist, gehen Formulierungen wie *SMS schicken* oder eben *WhatsApp schicken* vielen Sprechern leichter über die Lippen als das relativ komplizierte *eine Kurznachricht über SMS schicken* oder *eine WhatsApp-Nachricht schicken*. Stilfragen fallen hier Trends zum Opfer und technische Präzision spielt keine Rolle, lediglich der Kommunikationskanal ist relevant, da er bei Sender und Empfänger passen muss.

---

<sup>1</sup>Anpassung an die sprachliche Realität vs. technischer Korrektheit:
Der Duden führt inzwischen *[**die/das** SMS](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/SMS_per_SMS_verschickte_Nachricht)* als Begriff für die Kurznachricht selbst auf, der zugrunde liegende Dienst ist *[**der** SMS](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/SMS_Nachrichtendienst)*.

Comment: Gute Antwort. Ich denke mir geht "eine Whatsapp" sehr viel mehr gegen den Strich als "eine SMS", da "SMS" ein an sich bedeutungsloser Begriff ist, den man erstmal mental dekodieren muss um seine Unsinnigkeit zu entdecken. Bei "einer Whatsapp" hingegen ist *die App* direkt im Wort! Aber am Ende ist es das gleiche Phänomen, das ist richtig.

Comment: @deceze Im Zweifelsfall den Sprechern nicht zu viel Hirn oder gar Absicht unterstellen - "das sagt man halt so". Vorhandene Sprachmuster spielen eine große Rolle bei der Neuschöpfung von Begriffen. Ich denke, an SMS als Begriff haben wir uns einfach schon gewöhnt, in ein paar Jahren könnte das mit WhatsApp ähnlich sein. Obwohl - dann gibt es wahrscheinlich schon den Nachfolger des Nachfolgers mit eigener Begrifflichkeit ^_^

Comment: Ich glaube ich werde alt... ;-(

Comment: Der Name _Whatsapp_ enthält zwar _App_, ist aber auch keine sinnvolle Zusammensetzung; er basiert auf einem (nur für deutschsprachige Nutzer halbwegs stimmigen) Wortspiel mit _What's up?_.

Comment: @chirlu Wieso "nur für deutschsprachige Nutzer"?!

Comment: Der gesuchte Begriff ist übrigens [Metonymie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymie).

Comment: @deceze: Nur im Deutschen reimen sich _App_ und _up_ (unter Umständen, nämlich wenn man nicht _Äpp_ sagt).

Comment: @chirlu Da man aber Englisch sprechen muß, um dieses Wortspiel zu verstehen, und der Name von Amerikanern geschaffen wurde, denke ich mal, daß das auch in anderen Sprachen verständlich ist... :)

Comment: @chirlu: Wieso sollten sich "App" und "up" reimen, damit es ein stimmiges Wortspiel ist? "WhatsDown" wäre beispielsweise genauso ein stimmiges Wortspiel, obwohl sich da nichts reimt, so lange das "down" nur irgendwie die gewünschte Botschaft vermittelt. Das Wortspiel entsteht schon dadurch, dass das ursprüngliche Wort "up" durch etwas ersetzt wird, was eine erkennbare Beziehung - eine inhaltliche oder klangliche Verbindung - aufweist. Es muss nicht unbedingt genau gleich klingen.

Comment: Ich ziehe die Aussage zurück.

Answer (score 5):

Wie **chirlu** in seinem Kommentar schreibt, könnte man das Phänomen wohl als Metonymie bezeichnen. Evtl. auch als Synekdoche - ganz treffend finde ich das allerdings alles nicht.
Die Sache mit der Sprachökonomie von **anion** kommt der Sache ziemlich nahe.

Vielleicht sollte man neben der offensichtlichen Parallele bei SMS noch anderes mit einbeziehen und den Blick etwas weiter öffnen:

Bisher hat interessanterweise niemand "E-Mail" erwähnt. Dieses Wort steht ganz ursprünglich ja eigentlich für das System, elektronische Post zu verschicken. Im zweiten Schritt bezeichnet es dann eben auch eine einzelne solche Nachricht. Schließlich kann man mittlerweile auch im Deutschen "mailen" - und kein normaler Mensch hat ein Problem damit.
Bei "SMS" befinden wir uns im gleichen Prozess (zugegebenermaßen etwas verzögert). Und bei "WhatsApp" geht diese Entwicklung eben erst los.

Da das i.d.R. auch bei Dateiendungen funktioniert ("die PDF" statt "die PDF-Datei" etc.), gibt es für normale Sprachnutzer keinen nachvollziehbaren Grund, das hier im vorliegenden Fall nicht ähnlich ökonomisch zu machen.

Missverständnisse sind meist nicht zu befürchten (außer es wird dem Hörer durch [zu starke Abkürzung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17812/what-does-schreib-mal-wa-mean) unnötig schwer gemacht).

Das kann man schrecklich finden oder nicht - solange man selbst aber jeden Tag E-Mails verschickt und sich nicht die Mühe macht, diese als "E-Mail-Nachrichten" zu bezeichnen, sollte man vielleicht anderen auch "eine WhatsApp" durchgehen lassen.
Sprache entwickelt sich beim Gebrauch, die Regeln kommen erst hinterher.

Edit:
Vielleicht bedenkenswert ist die Tatsache, dass sich im Deutschen "die Mail" für eine E-Mail-Nachricht durchgesetzt hat. Absolut legitim und praktisch. Den wenigsten ist aber bewusst, dass sie damit (wie bei "Handy" oder "Bodybag") ein deutsches Wort benutzen, das so im Englischen nicht verwendet wird. Dort ist "mail" nach wie vor einfach "Post" - und kann wie das deutsche "Post" nicht für eine einzelne Sendung stehen. Man könnte also auch hier die "Unkenntnis der Masse" ins Feld führen - meines Erachtens bringt das allerdings wenig, sondern wirkt schlimmstenfalls kleinlich und elitär.

Comment: Wie ich auch schon weiter oben schrieb, ich glaube in diesem Fall geht es mir mehr gegen den Strich, da sich die Wortherkunft schlechter eignet für diese verkürzte Form. "Die Mail" – eine Mail ist an sich traditionell bezeichnend für einen Brief oder ein Paket. "Eine Mail schicken" ist daher absolut natürlich. Das Transportsystem hier ist "the postal system". Bei SMS oder PDF hat das Wort an sich wenig Bedeutung, weswegen es nicht problematisch klingt. Aber *die WhatsApp* hat eine eingebaute Bedeutung die *die App* bezeichnet... ich möchte da differenzieren... :-/

Comment: Hmm, ich glaube ich kann Dich im Grundsatz verstehen - allerdings sehe ich da ein paar nicht ganz richtige Annahmen: "Mail" bezeichnet ganz ursprünglich den Postsack, dann den Postservice und -Auslieferung. Nie eine einzelne Poststendung. Erst im Zusammenhang mit E-Mail taucht der Singular für eine einzelne Sendung auf. Das entspricht *exakt* der App-Sache. Bei SMS steckt "Service" drin - nicht viel anders als bei "App"... wobei ich Dir natürlich Recht gebe, dass letzteres wesentlich offensichtlicher ist.

Comment: Hinweis in eigener Sache: Mit [dem Totum-pro-parte-Kommentar](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25449/schick-uns-eine-whatsapp#comment60375_25458) wollte ich nur die lateinische Grammatik berichtigen, aber nicht sagen, daß es ein solcher Fall wäre. Es liegt aber eine Metonymie vor (von der _pars pro toto_ und _totum pro parte_ Spezialfälle sind). Das hatte ich in [einem anderen Kommentar](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25449/schick-uns-eine-whatsapp#comment60353_25450) gesagt. :-)

Comment: Ich würde gern anmerken, dass die Sache bei SMS durchaus nochmal anders gelagert ist als bei WhatsApp (und ebenso anderen vergleichbaren Messengern, nehmen wir mal der Einfachheit halber *Line* als Beispiel). Zumindest ich persönlich habe auch keine Vorbehalte dagegen, mit "SMS" die einzelne Textnachricht zu versenden, und zwar genau deswegen, weil der Begriff "SMS" *in der Praxis* nicht anderweitig belegt ist. Mit WhatsApp, der App, komme ich durchaus in Berührung - ich kann die App auf dem Smartphone installiert haben oder nicht, ich kann sie öffnen, dort einen Account haben. Dasselbe ...

Comment: ... gilt für andere Apps wie das zuvor genannte *Line*, obwohl dieses gar nicht das Wort "App" im Namen trägt. Daher wirkt auf mich die Verwendung von "WhatsApp" bzw. "Line" als Bezeichnung einer *Nachricht* im betreffenden Dienst äußerst befremdlich. Ganz anders bei "SMS", womit ich eben nicht als Ganzes "hantiere". "SMS" ist nicht in dem Sinn eine App, sondern ist i.A. bereits "fest eingebaut" - und wenn man wirklich die (gewöhnlich vorinstallierte) App meint, spricht man vielmehr von einer "SMS-App". Man kann auch nicht "bei SMS sein" oder nicht nicht, sondern hat eine Telefonnummer.

Answer (score 3):

> Gibt es für dieses Phänomen eine Bezeichnung?

Wenn man schnell den für die allermeisten Menschen immer noch gut verständlichen Satz "Schick uns eine Whatsapp" sagt, anstatt die Sätze der Richtigkeit halber im Detail inhaltlich korrekt zu formulieren, ist das meiner Meinung nach am ehesten dem Phänomen der "Sprachökonomie" zuzuordnen.

Nachtrag:

Bei [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprach%C3%B6konomie#Sprach.C3.B6konomie_als_Triebkraft_von_Sprecher_und_H.C3.B6rer) wird das ganz gut beschrieben. Wikipedia ist nicht immer die zuverlässigste Quelle, aber der verlinkte Absatz ist gut zutreffend und kann auch auf das von dir beschriebene Phänomen angewendet werden.

Comment: Ich halte es eher für Unkenntnis der Sprecher, die einfach nicht wissen, was eine WhatApp ist und was eine Nachricht, ähnlich wie bei SMS, Die Leute wissen es nicht richtig und verwenden es falsch, setzen sich aber aufgrund ihrer Masse durch, bis auch die wenigen, die es besser wissen, sich der Übermacht beugen.

Answer (score 1):

Ich werfe mal *pars pro toto* in den Raum, ein Teil (Whatsapp) für das Ganze (Whatsapp-Nachricht). Wenn man sich darüber ärgert, muss man sich konsequenterweise auch über "Washington will mehr Druck auf Moskau ausüben" (Die Städte führen ein Eigenleben? Die Stadtverwaltung von Washington fährt der Stadtverwaltung von Moskau an den Karren?), was eigentlich "Die Regierung der USA will mehr Druck auf die Regierung Russlands ausüben" heißt.

Comment: Quasi ein *toto pro pars*... Wobei der Vergleich besser passen würde wenn man "die USA" statt "Washington" benutzen würde. Etwas Übergeordnetes für ein Teil desselben.

Comment: @deceze: _Totum pro parte_.